# Why is an int promoted in multiplication but not division?

Tags: c, types, casting

It's my understanding that when multiplying, for example, a float and an int the int gets promoted to a float and so the product can have a fractional part.  On the other hand, when dividing a float by an int there's no promotion and any fractional part of the quotient is discarded.  What's the reason for this asymmetry?

```
float f1 = 13.3;
int i1 = 2;
float product = f1 * i1;  // Product will be 26.6
float quotient = f1 / i1;  // Quotient will be 6.0
```

Edit: Well, I guess I was just wrong.  An int is promoted in division, too.  Right?  The truncation only applies to division with two ints.  Right?  What's the site best-practice here, should I just delete this question since it's so off base?

Comment: Why do you think that?

Comment: Your understanding is incorrect. There is no asymmetry.

Comment: Quotient is 6.65. Voting to close as "cannot be reproduced"

Comment: [Works as expected](http://ideone.com/6Tfh8W)

Answer (score 3):

> On the other hand, when dividing a float by an int there's no promotion and any fractional part of the quotient is discarded.

That is simply not correct. The fractional part is kept. The multiplication and division operations work in the same way in this sense.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float f1 = 13.3;
    int i1 = 2;
    float product = f1 * i1;  // Product will be 26.6
    float quotient = f1 / i1;  // Quotient 

    printf( "product = %f\n",product );
    printf( "quotient = %f\n", quotient );
}
```

then the output is

```
product = 26.600000
quotient = 6.650000
```

According to the C Standard (6.5.5 Multiplicative operators)

> 3 The usual arithmetic conversions are performed on the operands.

and (6.3.1.8 Usual arithmetic conversions)

> Otherwise, if the corresponding real type of either operand is float,
>   the other operand is converted, without change of type domain, to a
>   type whose corresponding real type is float.62)